# How can I make this char triangle reflect vertically?

Tags: javascript

```js
for(var i = 5; i > 0; i--){
    var th = "";
    for(var k = i - 1; k > 0; k--) {
        th += " ";
    }
    th += ("a");

    for(var j = 5 - i; j > 0; j--){
        th += ("a");
    }
    console.log(th);
}
```

I want to reflect it so it looks like an isosceles triangle. I got most of it but the last two rows are too long. Row 4 by 1 char and row 5 by 2. Here's my attempt:

```js
for(var i = 5; i > 0; i--){
    var th = "";
    for(var k = i - 1; k > 0; k--) {
        th += " ";
    }
    th += ("a");

    for(var j = 5 - i; j > 0; j--){
        th += ("a");
        for(var h = th.length; h > th.length - j; h--){
            th += ("a");
        }
    }
    console.log(th);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short solution using `String.repeat` function:

```
var char = "a", level = 5, i = 1, step;
for (; i <= level; i++) {
    step = (i == 1)? i : ((!step)? i + 2 : step + 2);
    console.log(" ".repeat(level - i) + char.repeat(step));
}
```

The output:

```
    a
   aaa
  aaaaa
 aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm saving each output and then displaying it in reverse order.

```js
var z = [];
for(var i = 5; i > 0; i--){
    var th = "";
    for(var k = i - 1; k > 0; k--) {
        th += " ";
    }
    th += ("a");

    for(var j = 5 - i; j > 0; j--){
        th += ("a");
        for(var h = th.length; h > th.length - j; h--){
            th += ("a");
        }
    }
    console.log(th);
    z.push(th);
}

z.reverse();
for(a in z){
   console.log(z[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Written in simplest way, It may help you

```
var numOfLines=10;
var printChar='a';
var printString=printChar;
for(var i=0;i<numOfLines;i++){
   var numOfSpaces = numOfLines - i;
   var spaces = "";
   for (var j = 0; j < numOfSpaces; j++) {
            spaces += " ";
        }
  console.log(spaces + printString + spaces);
  printString += printChar + printChar;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4csmqmeu/